# Equivalent Valuations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Def: A valuation on a ring $A$ (commutative with identity) is a map $\lvert \cdot \rvert : A \to \Gamma \cup \{0\}$ such that for all $a,b\in A$,

$\lvert a+b \rvert \leq \max\{\lvert a \rvert, \lvert b \rvert \}$,

$\lvert ab \rvert=\lvert a \rvert\lvert b \rvert$,

$\lvert 0 \rvert=0$ and $\lvert 1 \rvert=1$,

where $\Gamma$ is a totally ordered group.

Def: Two valuations $\lvert \cdot \rvert_1,\lvert \cdot \rvert_2$ on $A$ are said to be equivalent if for every $a,b \in A$ we have that $\lvert a \rvert_1 \leq \lvert b\rvert_1$ if and only if $\lvert a \rvert_2 \leq \lvert b\rvert_2$.

I study valuations right now and saw the second definition. I tried to find examples about equivalent valuations but I couldn't. Can you help me please?

Comment: What examples of valuations do you know (say, on $\Bbb Q$, or whatever rings you have studied)? Then one could start to think about which of these might be equivalent.

Comment: And here's a hint: Often, when you have a valuation and raise it to a certain power, it will again be a valuation.

Comment: That is useful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two examples of equivalent valuations that are not identically equivalent, fix a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p \geq 2$ and consider the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ as our base ring. We will construct now the standard $p$-adic norm on $\mathbb{Z}$, $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ defined by first considering the function
$$
v_p(n) := \begin{cases} 
0 & {\rm if}\, n = 0; \\
\max\lbrace m \in \mathbb{N} \; : \; p^m|n \rbrace & {\rm if}\, n \ne 0;
\end{cases}
$$
and then defining $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p$ by saying that
$$
\lvert n \rvert_p = \begin{cases}
0 & {\rm if}\, n = 0; \\
p^{-v_p(n)} & {\rm if}\, n \ne 0.
\end{cases}
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It can then be easily verified that $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p$ satisfies the properties you ask of it. Now, to get an equivalent valuation, fix a constant $a > 1$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and with $\gcd(a,p) =1$. We can define a map $\lVert \cdot\rVert_p:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ by defining
$$
\lVert n \rVert_p := \begin{cases}
0 & {\rm if}\, n = 0; \\
a^{-v_p(n)} & {\rm if}\, n \ne 0.
\end{cases}
$$
It is then just as straightforward to show  that $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ satisfies the properties you ask as well, but that $\lvert \cdot \rvert_p \ne \lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ by considering what each map does on $-p$. However, the maps are equivalent in the sense you request because since $a, p > 1$, a standard calculus argument shows that
$$
\lvert n \rvert_p \leq \lvert m \rvert_p
$$
if and only if
$$
\lVert n \rVert_p \leq \lVert m \rVert_p.
$$

Comment: Is this equivalent to saying that $v$ is the first nonzero index, when we write $n$ as a $p$-adic integer? i.e. $n = \sum _ {i=0} ^{\infty} a_ip^i$